# Returning the same object from Iterator<?>

Tags: java, performance, optimization, iterator

Is it valid - i.e., within the contact, for `Iterator` to return the same (mutable) object as a prior iteration, or a new object with shared mutable state as prior object?  That is, may one call to `next()` to invalidate the object returned by a prior call, as long as it is documented?

I understand perfectly well that this isn't a good idea *in general*, and I don't make a habit of it.

However, there are some cases where reusing the same underlying object, or new object with shared internals (thus possibly invalidating internals of an object returned earlier) has a significant and measurable in some cases.  A good example would be when the object returned from the iterator points with some offset and length into a buffer array held by the containing `Iterable`, and this array may be overwritten when the subsequent object is retrieved.

Granted this violates the principle of least astonishment, and may be client unfriendly - but I'm curious if it violates the contact of `Iterator` - as long as I document it, am I playing within the rules?

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) seems to have been written with a focus on collections, where sharing state between `next()` calls is probably meaningless, but `Iterator` is a general purpose interface (you can implement without a backing collection or even without a backing *anything*).

Basically I'm trying to implement something comparable, performance-wise, to the flyweight pattern, but to retain the niceties of Java iterators.

Iterators following this pattern would be safe to use in the following way:

```
for (Foo foo : FooIterable) {
  if (foo.method()) {
    System.println("ha!");
  }
}
```

since each instance of `foo` never escapes from one iteration to the other.  However, something like the following would not work in general:

```
List<Foo> allTheFoos = ...;
for (Foo foo : FooIterable) {
  allTheFoos.add(foo);
}

for (Foo foo : allTheFoos) {
  ...
}
```

Since the `foo`s in the first loop are stored away and thus escape their iteration.  When you access them later, their state may be invalid (e.g., they may all look like  the last `foo` returned from the initial iteration.

Comment: In my defense I searched here and on Google, but my search-term-fu was apparently weak today.

Answer (score 0):

A `List` can contain the same object several times, and its `Iterator` would return this object where it occurs in the list. Hence this is probably not something that is forbidden by the contract. A `Set` should not contain duplicates so would not return the same object twice.

Collections never modify or invalidate they members, however there is something similar to your situation inside the Iterator itself: it becomes invalid (and throws exception on call) if the collection has been modified. This may be hint to solution that to do when returned objects become invalid.

Maybe your Iteration could better return wrappers about that changing object to be sure that all calls on the previously returned, now invalid wrapper throw exception.

Comment: Right, I guess the first sentence isn't narrow enough - I agree that returning the same object is OK in that scenario (where returning the 2nd copy of an object doesn't affect the first) - but what about cases where returning later objects invalidates earlier objects?

Comment: Yup, that's crossed my mind.  You don't even necessarily need a wrapper, just maybe a modCount or something in the object, compared against the modcount of the iterator and throw if they are not the same (i.e., if the object escaped its iteration). That's not always feasible if the shared state is exposed by some method on the object, however - e.g., if it returns an array without a defensive copy, you won't be able to detect later accesses to it.